# Compose Desktop chain a Component to another

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop

since `ConstraintLayout` is not available in `Compose Desktop`
i need to chain a `Text` into a `Divider`.

these two Components are in different parents.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 32.dp, bottom = 64.dp).fillMaxSize(), 
    contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().width(128.dp).padding(start = 12.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        .
        .
        .
        Divider(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp).width(72.dp), color = borderColor)
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

this is my `Divider` with its Parents

and another place out of this `Box` but in same screen, I have a `Text` inside of a `Surface`.

```
 Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) { 
    Text("qwerty")
}
```

I need to align this `Text` to bottom of that `Divider`.

since `ConstraintLayout` is not available I dont know how to do that.
any help?

by the way I can not change the `UI` structure so there must be some way like chaining.